# how possible if and else execute together?

Tags: java, android, debugging

i have custom view in android and override touch event that have two block if end else code handle two type of touch event in color way and normal.

but when rise onTouchEvent in my custom view two block code of (if and else) execute !!! how this possible????

i get video of this issue that complete show what occured.
this is my debugging video link :
https://www.mediafire.com/?lcw7rk0z5sp99xs

pleaseeeeeeee before judge see video.
thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your onTouchEvent in just called for once ?

Comment: Are you ok ? This is impossible you are doing wrong just paste your touch code

Comment: this is only possible if it is called more than once, one time the if statement is executed, the other time the else statement

Comment: Put [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) together.

Comment: hey Ajay Pandya you see my video?

Answer (score 1):

yes it may be execute . because touch event called twice once for UP and one for DOWN when you code if(for UP) it will call and in next cycle for same touch else will run

Comment: i debug step by step in android studio please see my debug video

Comment: i cant see video. just paste code i ll see . may i help you

Comment: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (colorful){
            return onTouchColor(event);
        }
        else {
            return onTouchNormal(event);
        }
    }

Comment: so what is colorful. does it chane in onTouchColor(event) function ?